# When does the 'done' value change?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql code that will iterate through the list and changes the total salary field. However, what I don't understand is when dose the value of 'done' change for the loop to stop?. Becaunse UNTIL DONE depends on the value to change. This is an example from a book. Anyway, here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateSalary() BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE current_dnum INT;
  DECLARE dnumcur CURSOR FOR SELECT dnumber FROM deptsal;
  DECLARE continue HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET DONE = 1;
  OPEN dnumcur;
  REPEAT
   FETCH dnumcur INTO current_dnum;
   UPDATE deptsal SET totalSalary = (SELECT SUM(salary) FROM employee
   WHERE dno=current_dnum) WHERE dnumber=current_dnum;
   UNTIL done
   END REPEAT;
   CLOSE dnumcur;
   END$$
delimiter ;
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of done will be changed when the cursor does not find any more data in the data set.

This is controlled by the handler in your code:

```
DECLARE continue HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
```

This is basically saying, when there is no more data in the data set for this cursor, set the value of done to 1.

There is some extra information on this at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html - that reads "NOT FOUND: Shorthand for the class of SQLSTATE values that begin with '02'. This is relevant within the context of cursors and is used to control what happens when a cursor reaches the end of a data set. If no more rows are available, a No Data condition occurs with SQLSTATE value '02000'. To detect this condition, you can set up a handler for it or for a NOT FOUND condition."

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I can make sense of it